# Does any has a sample Alexa music skill code? Including all the required directives?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to build Alexa MUSIC skill. I was following through official documentation but not get much help. What to upload in catalog, what to implement in required directives (GetPlayableContent,
Initiate, GetNextItem).

Links:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/music-skills/steps-to-create-a-music-skill.html#step-3
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/music-skills/upload-catalogs.html

I've been trying other ways like using Audio Player interface and everything but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating a radio Alexa skill. Your radio skill will be implemented using AudioPlayer interface, please find more information on the link below:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html .

We have an AudioPlayer sample skill which actually streams from a radio station already to which you can refer. That can be found here:
https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

You will need to change the url stream and add your own. Please take into account that the URL you provide in the audioItem.stream.url property must meet these requirements:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements

We have a course called "from zero to hero" in our Youtube channel, please see the first video of this course that will help you to create your skill:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzTKDu7Qgjs

You could also use RSK (Radio Skills kit), RSK is a free, no-code solution for radio providers to create, manage, and promote radio stations on Alexa.

Please see eligibility requirements and more information:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/radio-skills-kit

Comment: Thanks for responding.

I have one more question when should we use AudioPlayer Interface and when should we use Alexa Music Skill? I have went through documentation but did not find any difference in terms of functionality.